# Upload\Download speeds NAS

Tags: networking, download, nas

Any ideas why when you download ANYTHING from ANYWHERE on the Internet, most of the time you can download at your max DOWNLOAD speeds (because YOU are the CLIENT and where you're downloading from is the SERVER) but when someone remotely downloads from MY synology NAS server via DSM or via a shared link or via a mapped drive, the downloader is only able to download the files at MY UPLOAD speed (which is 40X slower). what is the trick to get MY server to be seen as a true SERVER so people can download from me at THEIR download speeds?

If you answer that my upload speed is a bottle-neck, then I would ask - so does every website in the world have an upload speed at 20MB\s (200Mbps) or more? Because that's the speed I download from every website in the world (unless they limited the speed intentionally)

The way I understand it is that uploads and downloads are doing the same thing - transferring data back or forth through the same cable - so TECHNICALLY, there should be no speed difference between the two. The only reason downloads are faster is because ISPs do this on purpose to limit traffic clutter in the wires. The decided that more people need to download so that's the one they made faster. (excuse the amateur way of explaining it - but you get the point). So when data is being transferred from one person to another - how does an ISP ever decide who is the UPLOADER and who is the DOWNLOADER? Do they check the upload speed of both sides and give the transfer the lowest speed from the two? I thought that when an ISP would see that I am the SERVER - it would let the connection speed go as high as my DOWNLOAD speed.

So if you say that EVERY site that I download from at 20MB\s MUST have an upload speed of at least 20MB\s-  even this wouldn't be accurate because let's say 100 people are downloading from the same site, at the same time... so yes, we all know of site's crashing from too many simultaneous connections, but 100 people are not a lot to crash a server, so if 100 people would be downloading at the same time at 20MB\s, that would mean (according to what you're saying) that the site they are downloading from would need an upload speed of at least 2GB\s. Is this even possible?

EDIT 01:
Again, why is MY ISP involved with what the person downloading from me is doing? When HE clicks on the download link - it's HIS ISP that should be saying "oh, you want to download? No problem, you can download at your download speed." How come when "I" download from somewhere, my ISP allows ME to download at my download speed and doesn't say "sorry, you can't download at your fast download speed because that server you are trying to download from - his ISP is limiting the data transfer to their upload speed."

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76516/discussion-on-question-by-zvi-twersky-upload-download-speeds-nas).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your ISP isn't artificially limiting your upload speed just so they can make money. Most "home" broadband services are "asymmetric" in that you traffic going towards you (nominally referred to as download) is always faster than traffic going away from you (upload).

This is a technical limitation in the way the cable services were designed, specifically because for "home" services they are intended for "consumer" use rather than "server" use.

The fact that your cable can support a specific speed is irrelevant. The communications standard that allows you to transmit and receive over that single cable was designed in such a way that it allows more data to flow in one direction than the other.

For more information you should read [Wikipedia: ADSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_digital_subscriber_line).

The key problem is that you have only a single (effective) wire connection to your exchange. You are trying to transmit and receive on that wire at the same time which means that you need to share the cable. To allow both to happen at the same time they split the frequencies being transmitted down the cable into "upload" and "download".

Below you can see that the upload frequency range is **a lot** smaller than the download frequency set. This is why you do not get the same speed in one direction compared to the other.

[image]
(From the above Wikipedia page)

If you had two connections, one in either direction, then you could have symmetric speeds, but almost every phone system used in the world relies on what is essentially one single "connection" over two bits of wire.

For "server" use cases you need to purchase a product that is balanced. If you need a service that provides the same speed up and down then you need to purchase a symmetric service.

Comment: Please see my "EDIT 01:" in my question for reply to this.

Comment: so is it correct to say that you're saying that one of two things must be true when I download from anywhere at speed of 200Mbps. 1: either they have a 200Mbps upload speed. 2: They have a symmetric Internet connection. Is this correct?

Comment: ok, I'm accepting this. I am guessing that all sites I download from, either large like youtube, facebook, or small - like your local bakeries site that's hosted on a local hosting server, all use symmetric services and that's why I can download - because they have upload speeds at least the speed of my download speed.

Comment: @ZviTwersky yes, they are all hosted in locations that have sufficient *outgoing* bandwidth, at least enough to supply you at your *incoming speed*. Similarly for you to supply to someone else your outgoing speed needs to be the same as or larger than their incoming speed, otherwise the limit is at your outgoing speed.

Answer (score 5):

If someone is downloading from you, your upload determines the available bandwidth. If you want a faster upload get a contract that has a bigger upload.

Most servers you can rent will have 100 Mbit or 1 Gbit upload speeds. Your NAS likely has as well but your ISP and/or maybe the used technology limits your upload. Part of this is to prevent someone to run commercial services on residential contracts.

*Edit*:
You are correct that upload and download are a direction. With currently technology you're usually using a technology that supports full duplex communication. So you can upload and download at the same time. If you don't have that you need to wait every so often or switch every so often which usually makes things (even) slower. So your ISP is limiting you but the used technology might also limit you in what you can do. Another way to think about this is to partition a wide channel into multiple smaller ones and deciding on a ratio on how many you want to be used for upload or download. Usually you get a contract which is (behind the scenes) related to a profile (e.g. a [VDSL profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDSL#Profiles)) which in turn limits your speed. To "reverse" it you would need to change that configuration and there is no dynamic determination of who's uploading or downloading but rather a side A and side B with a fixed ratio.

As for the speed, current Ethernet speeds are up to [40 Gbit/100 Gbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/100_Gigabit_Ethernet) so yes, it's possible. In addition with cloud services you might have a whole array of machines to answer requests. You're correct that the backend networks have to be beefy enough but it seems like they are (for what you do). Keep in mind that it might just be your usage profile that makes it seem like you're always able to download using high speeds.

Usually if you hop across the oceans with your connection (especially connecting to Asia, though that is becoming less of an issue as well it seems) you will notice a difference (be it latency or bandwidth).

*Answer to Edit01*:
You can't deliver at the speed the other one wants to download at. That's why you can't saturate his download. You are limited to upload at the speed you're uploading with. The smallest denominator (your upload) is limiting the process as a whole.

Comment: I hear what you're saying and would like to add to my question to clarify my thoughts. Please read what I added to my original question.

Comment: So to your answer on edit 01: so what you're saying is that ANY site I am able to download from at 200Mbps (20MB\s) - THEY must have an upload speed of at LEAST 200Mbps?

Comment: @ZviTwersky They must have an upload speed greater then 200 Mbps.  They are providing bandwidth to every client connected to them. They likely have several connections in order to serve hundreds of clients at those speeds.  They also are not limited to copper wires, likely using fiber, which is 10-100x faster then copper

Comment: Isn't that the most simplest answer? That anywhere you download from MUST have an upload speed at LEAST as high as your download speed in order for you to be able to download at YOUR download speed. Why so many comments and down-votes? Was it not clear what I was asking? Was is not clear that I UNDERSTOOD that my upload speed was a bottle neck on my NAS but was trying to understand why.

Comment: Additionally, these servers in a data center are not limited to residential ISO rules, you are at the mercy of your ISP

Answer (score 5):

First we must establish the definitions of "*download*" and "*upload*" - they are confused all too readily.

- "*Download*" - the movement of data towards a given entity.
- "*Upload*" - the movement of data away from a given entity.

In this context, "*your house*" or "*their house*" is the entity in question. The given entity is also usually closer to the user or operator of the system - "*you*" or "*them*", not "*the internet*".

---

As Mokubai has pointed out, most residential connections are *asymmetric* - that is the download and upload rates are different. As you've correctly surmised, this is because home users will typically want to *download* much more data than they *upload* - think of an HTTP request/response. The request is going to be kilobytes, while the response could be huge. Similarly with video streams, etc... There is much more data coming *into* the house than going out, so it gets a larger share of the bandwidth.

---

Now, when considering two residential connections that are communicating with each other (let's just consider data flow in one direction), the terminology is the same... "*Download*" and "*Upload*" are link-oriented concepts (i.e: the link from your ISP to your house / ADSL / Cable), not connection-oriented concepts (i.e: the link from "*your house*" to "*their house*").

[image: dataflow terminology]

*Note: these diagrams are massively simplified - the internet is a complex place, and there are many other topics not discussed here - [latency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latency_(engineering)) / [contention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contention_(telecommunications)) / etc... Additionally, you may find that your download bandwidth exceeds the bandwidth available to many websites and other services as residential connections get faster and faster*

---

We are now able to apply the terminology. For example:

- Your connection has 200 Mbps download, 20 Mbps upload
- Their connection has 70 Mbps download, 5 Mbps upload

In this case, transferring data from "*your house*" to "*their house*" takes the following route, and as such, the data rate is limited by *your* upload speed - 20 Mbps.

[image: data transfer]

The inverse is also true. Here the limit is 5 Mbps.

[image: data transfer]

---

Now you might appreciate that discussing servers and websites is quite a different topic. Typically websites are hosted on servers with *symmetric* 100 Mbps or 1 Gbps+ connections that are connected close to the backbone. "*Symmetric*" meaning that the upload and download bandwidth is the same.

Yes, if such a server becomes busy, then this bandwidth is shared between all clients - you will see your download speeds drop.

To counter this, bigger sites are hosted by *many* servers that are geographically distributed, using [Content Delivery Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) and the like to facilitate local and fast access to data.

Comment: Not all, we have symmetric residential here. VZ FiOS 100/100. And we actually receive 125/125 bursting. Very nice answer btw.

Comment: Thanks @Tim_Stewart - updated... I was wondering if FTTP might start breaking the phenomenon.