# Remote fibre connections

Tags: internet-connection, fiber

I'm wondering if it is possible to utilise a single fibre connection's bandwidth from two geographic locations.

Site A has a 35Mb fibre connection and Site B has 1.0Mb ... long story buy we are geographically remote with little possibility of connecting the second property.

Is it possible to permanently link Site B to Site A remotely to utilise the 35Mb router's bandwidth ?  I've been googling but can't seem to get the terminology correct for what I need.  'VPN tunnelling' sounds like something I commissioned a few years back but ... I've no idea really !!  :o)

Help or 'Not Possible' comments appreciated ... Thx

Comment: If I understand, then all of the traffic from Site B would still n=have to traverse the 1MB pipe to get to Site A anyway so there would be no benefite to creating a VPN tunnel to Site A. If you want faster pipes at Site B you will have to upgrade the physical components that provide the connection at Site B.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1316762/707676) for discussion on connecting two sites, and how upload / download bandwidth works...

Fundamentally, you *could* put in a VPN connection between **A** and **B**, with all of **B**'s traffic routed via **A**... however you are still limited by **B**'s bandwidth.

If you were to implement VPN:

- In the best-case situation you could get a slight boost for certain content types by using compression (with suitably powerful routers / computers at either end). As the web moves more and more to HTTPS, you are unlikely to benefit from such compression due to the "*random*" nature of encrypted data.
- In the worst-case situation you'll get an even worse internet experience due to the additional latency incurred, and the fact that VPNs don't really like running over severely restricted bandwidth.

If you are keen to improve the web performance of **B**'s connection, then you could look into a caching proxy, but this won't help with lots of things such as streaming videos or large portions of the dynamic content found on the web today which is (by nature) impossible to cache.

---

If however you are toying with the possibility of running *your own* cable from **A** to **B** (e.g: copper or fibre Ethernet), then yes, you could drop **B**'s internet connection entirely.

However, you will need to be careful doing this, as most (if not all) residential ISPs will have strict wording surrounding the sharing of a connection from one premises to another (i.e: you can't, and they'll disconnect you if they find out). If you're thinking of this, it would be sensible to check with your provider whether this is a breach of your terms.